# How to use str(x) to call a variable

Tags: string, class, attributes

im coding a game, and i have Square class

```
class Square:
    def __init__(self, name, pos) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.pos = pos #pos is (x,y)
        self.unit = None
```

when i create a Square i give it the name Square+"x"+"y" using :

```
Square(("square"+str(x)+str(y)), (x,y))
```

But i dont know how to call this object. Let's say i want to change the unit that is on this square, i'd like to do

```
square+str(x)+str(y).unit = warrior
```

or something of the sort. How do use str(x) and str(y) to call my object?

I tried doing

```
square+str(x)+str(y).unit = warrior
```

but of cours square is not a string and cannot be added to strings.

```
"square"+str(x)+str(y).unit = warrior
```

obviously does not work either.
So i tried changing the name, to ("square", str(x)+str(y)) But then if i try to give my unit a square :

```
unit.square = ("square",str(x)+str(y))
```

this will not call the Square object, it is giving an attribute to my unit that is a pair of strings.

To sumarize, id like to be able to do :

```
for x in range(n):
    for y in range(n):
        square + str(x) + str(y) = Square(name, (x,y))
        square + str(x) + str(y).unit = warrior
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a bit of reading from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) to understand python objects.

In short you initialize an object by calling its class name and storing it into a variable.
I also suggest to use a bit more variable to make your code more readable.

```
//store the name
squareName = "square" + str(x) + str(y)

//store the "Square" object
mySquare = Square(squareName, (x,y))

//Change the property "unit"
mySquare.unit = newUnit
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this helps. Although im not sure this solves my problem. 

The issue is that i have many squares, i'd like to be able to change attributes directly using x and y. So lets say i want every square with an x and y of same parity to be coloured red. 

Is it possible to do something like 

    //i know this will not work but you get the idea, i want to use x and y when i call my object
    mySquare_x_y = Square(squareName, (x,y))

or something like
    For Square in allSquare: #i dont know how
        if Square.x%2 ==Square.y%2:
            Square.color = red

Comment: @PEseyeux Can you edit your post with an image of the end result you want ?